# JQuery autocomplete dropdown hidden under FullCalendar events

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, fullcalendar

Sequence of html rendered on page : 
    1. Textbox, empty calendar 
    2. Calendar renders events 
    3. Type in the textbox to get auto-complete dropdown.

Can I show the autocomplete dropdown on top of calendar event divs? Thank you,

[image]

Fix : 
Z-idex worked together with position absolute : z-index: 10 ;position: absolute; top: 200px;

Comment: Do you have your z-indexes (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) set appropriately in the css for these elements? Be sure these elements have a "position" property, or z-index will not work correctly.

Comment: @gigantorTRON, no I haven't set z-index. Are you talking about calendar elements or dropdown or both ?

Comment: You'll want to set a z-index on any elements that need to overlay. In your example, the dropdown itself and the red/blue boxes (divs) in your screenshot. The z-index for the dropdown must be larger than the z-index for the divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the CSS property z-index. You can set the z-index of the dropdown to be larger than the other elements.

Careful on how you implement this. A common approach is to use intervals of 10 for the z-index, and something like 9999 as the "roof" that you know will never be exceeded. This ensures that in the future you can continue to add elements "between" existing ones.

Comment: Z-idex worked together with position absolute :
 z-index: 10 ;position: absolute; top: 200px;